# more about locally closedness

Tags: general-topology

"the union of a closed set & an open one is locally closed."

i think this statement is false in general but i have no counterexample.
does anybody have?

in what conditions that holds?
explain please.

is it true in real numbers with standard topology?

in particular case is the union of an open interval  & a closed subset in R locally closed?

thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$$X = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 < 1\} \cup \{ (x,0) : x \in [0,2]\}.$$

The union of the open unit disk with a straight line segment need not be locally closed, here the point $(1,0)$ has no neighbourhood $U$ such that $X\cap U$ is closed in $U$.

Generally, if $G$ is open and $F$ closed, $G\cup F$ need not be locally closed at points $x \in \overline{G}\cap F$, at all other points, it is locally closed. If $G\cup F$ contains a boundary point $x$ of $G$, it must contain an entire neighbourhood of $x$ relative to the boundary of $G$.

In $\mathbb{R}$, with $G = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^n}, \frac{1}{3^n}\right)$ and $F = \{0\}$ we also have a counterexample, $(G\cup F)\cap U$ is not closed in $U$ for any neighbourhood $U$ of $0$.

> in particular case is the union of an open interval & a closed subset in R locally closed?

That is the case. If $I$ is an open interval, and $F$ contains a boundary point $x$ of $I$, then in a small enough neighbourhood of $x$, $I\cup F$ looks like the closed set $\overline{I}\cup F$.

Comment: thnks can u complete the answer to this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736665/about-a-topological-space-that-satisfies-the-first-countability-axiom#736691

Comment: u say :"the union of an open interval & a closed subset in R is locally closed"? i cant understand u.explain please

Comment: Say the open interval is $I = (a,b)$, and say $a < c < b$. Every point of $I$ has a neighbourhood $U$ contained in $I$, and then $U\cap (I\cup F) = U\cap I = U$ is closed in $U$. Every point of $F\setminus \overline{I}$ has a neighbourhood $V$ with $V\cap \overline{I} = \varnothing$, and then $V\cap(I\cup F) = V\cap F$ is closed in $V$. So only the endpoints of $I$ are left to consider, if they belong to $I\cup F$. Take $a$ and suppose $a\in F$. Then for $W = (a-1,c)$, you have $W\cap (I\cup F) = W\cap ([a,b]\cup F)$ which is closed in $W$. The case for $b$ is similar.