# about a topological space that satisfies the first countability axiom

Tags: general-topology

Suppose X is a topological space that satisfies the first countability  axiom prove that for every pair of points in X for example x & y that fails the hausdorff condition (means that for every neighborhood of x like V  y has a neighborhood that intersects V)there is a sequence in X that converges to both x & y.

is this true for a general topological space?

Comment: You've misquoted what it means for $x$ and $y$ to fail the Hausdorff condition; it means that for every pair of neighborhoods $x \in U$ and $y \in V$, $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$. Your definition is trivially satisfied by any pair of points, by taking the neighborhood of $y$ to be all of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a neighbourhood base $\{A_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $x$ and  $\{B_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $y$, and assume without loss of generality that these two sequence of sets are decreasing. As the Hausdorff condition fails, there must be a point $z_n$ in every set $A_n \cap B_n$. The sequence $z_n$ converges to both $x$ and $y$.

**EDIT** Why can we assume the sets are decreasing?

Given the collection  $\{A_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$  we can define new sets

$$A_n' := \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k  $$

which are again open; are again a neighbourhood base; and are decreasing.

Comment: i thought the same as u at first  but i think its false because i think we cant say : without loss of generality that these two sequence of sets are decreasing.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

If $(U_n)_n$ is a countable local base at $x$, and $(V_n)_n$ is a countable local base for $y$, then $U_n\cap V_n=:W_n$ is non-empty for each $n$. If we define $U'_1=U_1,\ U'_2=U_1\cap U_2,...$, then it follows by induction that $U'_n=U_n\cap U'_{n-1}$ is a nested sequence, so we can assume that $U_{n+1}\subseteq U_n$ and $V_{n+1}\subseteq V_n$.
Now choosing $z_n\in W_n$ for every natural $n$ results in a sequence converging to both $x$ and $y$.

For an example of a space where two points $x$ and $y$ cannot be separated by neighborhoods but a sequence can only converge to one of them, consider the real line with the cocountable topology. Any neighborhoods intersect (there are no disjoint open sets), but if $(x_n)_n\to x$, then almost all $x_n$ are contained in the neighborhood $\Bbb R -\{x_n\ne x, n\in\Bbb N\}$, so the sequence must be eventually constant at $x$.

Comment: why do u think we can assume the neighborhoods are nested?

Comment: We can define $U'_1=U_1,\ U'_2=U_1\cap U_2,...$. By induction $U'_n=U_n\cap U'_{n-1}$ is a nested sequence.

Comment: thnks a lot. can u pls answer this too?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736621/more-about-locally-closedness

Comment: can u answer this:is this true for a general topological space?

Comment: @user115608: Are you asking if there is a sequence converging to both points in a space without first-countability if they don't have disjoint neighborhoods?

Comment: no i say:in a general topological space prove that for every pair of points in X for example x & y that fails the hausdorff condition (means that for every neighborhood of x like V y has a neighborhood that intersects V)there is a sequence in X that converges to both x & y.         i think its false so im looking for a counterexample.

Comment: @user115608: That's what I said, didn't I? You should really correct your statement about what it means to fail the Hausdorff condition. Didn't you read [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736665/about-a-topological-space-that-satisfies-the-first-countability-axiom/736691?noredirect=1#comment1536758_736665)

Comment: sorry!when i say hausdorff i mean what "Dustan Levenstein" says  now pls tell me the counterexample in general space

Comment: @user115608: See my answer.

Comment: thank u very much Stefan Hamcke! r u undergraduate math student?

Comment: I will complete my studies in the near future and receive a Diplom degree, which here in Germany is equivalent to a Master degree. So one could say I'm a graduate student.